# Почему инициализация счётчика в цикле for приводит к ошибке not a statement?

Tags: java, for

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = in.nextInt();
for (i; i > 0; i--){
    System.out.printf("Kvadrat %d is %d\n", i, i*i);
```

Проблему решил удалением инициализации счётчика, но мне хотелось бы узнать, почему этот код вызывает ошибку?

Comment: потому что ты его и не инициализируешь в самом цикле for........ переведи ошибку и поймёшь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1429134/#comment2547583_1429134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути Вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос:

> Проблему решил удалением **инициализации счётчика**...

То есть Вы в начале вместо того, чтобы **присвоить** переменной `i` какое-то значение, просто пишете данную переменную. Правила пишут, что первое выражение в `for`-циклах должно содержать [инициализацию счётчика](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 2):

Как уже об этом [сказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430335) @4500zenja, первое выражение в цикле `for` — это выражение [инициализации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```java
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Отдельно стоящее `i` не является [осмысленным](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16599239) [выражением](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html), поэтому компилятор выдает синтаксическую ошибку *not a statement*.

Чтобы исправить ошибку, вам нужно написать в качестве первого выражения цикла `for` что-то более осмысленное, например, объявление переменной:

```java
for (int i = in.nextInt(); i > 0; i--) {
    ...
}
```

Либо присваивание переменной:

```java
int i;
for (i = in.nextInt(); i > 0; i--) {
    ...
}
```

Если хотите объявить начало счетчика до цикла, то можно создать другую переменную:

```java
int start = in.nextInt();
for (int i = start; i > 0; i--) {
    ...
}
```

Еще один способ, который будет работать: выражение инициализации можно опустить:

```java
int i = in.nextInt()
for (; i > 0; i--) {
    ...
}
```